# What is the recipe for the Great White Ale?

Tags: fiz

All the clue says is, an import to Japan, "it stung of Coriander and billowed aroma of Citrus".

I need 100 units of this, but I don't know the recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beer needed to complete this event is called Maneater - Belgian Wit.  (get it?  great white ale, maneater... hur hur)